# How to install OpenOffice 3.1 in Headless Mode?

Tags: linux, centos, installation, openoffice

I need to setup OpenOffice in a linux box that will never have X installed.  Every time I run the setup program of the OpenOffice installer it complains that the system does not have an X Terminal.  I am using OOo_3.1.0_LinuxIntel_install_wJRE_en-US.tar.  I have done this headless install for version 2.4, but we are having some performance issues and we will like to test the 3.1 version.  The rpm -i *rpm does not work, since it is also looking for libgnome inside it.

We are trying to install the system in a CenOS 5.1.  Any ideas are welcome?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how will you be using OpenOffice on this box without a visual interface?

Comment: Glad you ask. I use this service as a server to convert word documents to pdf from all our websites.  Basically using the API (REST), I send a word document and receive back a PDF document. Hope that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the procedure I use to install Openoffice

```
tar -xzf .../OOo_3.1.X....
cd OOO[...]
mv *integration*.rpm desktop-integration
rpm -i *.rpm
```

The rpm ooobasis3.1-gnome-integration*.rpm has a dependency on libgnomevfs
and you don't need this package to run/install OpenOffice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just install an X Terminal (ie, xterm)? A quick look at [a random xterm RPM](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/12384579/com/xterm-215-8.el5.x86_64.rpm.html#requires) suggests that you can install one without needing to install an X server.

Comment: This server is in production, our policies do not allow us to install software without doing a whole lot of testing.  That is why installing services is a difficult path.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go with the package management of your distro (really think about it, they will provide security updates!)

- Install the package that contains the xauth binary (ssh X forwarding won't work otherwise)
- ssh -Y $targethost
- Install with your local X Terminal

  - In case you don't have a running linux use cygwins xterm to emulate the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Using Yum,

Find the openoffice "headless" package and install it.

```
openoffice.org-headless.x86_64
```

After that, use the following command

```
./soffice -nologo -nodefault -norestore -nocrashreport -nolockcheck -headless -nofirststartwizard -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp
```

and run it from the oo installation directory

Note that the headless package is no longer available on Apache OpenOffice 3.4